# SQL Server query month to date by week end date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I am new to SQL Server query. Sorry for the basic question. I have order qty by date,

In Query, How to calculate month to date by each Friday? (Sum of QTD From month start date TO each week Friday)

I have attached a screenshot for reference:

[[image]

Appreciate your help

Comment: which database you are using ????'

Comment: please tag the correct DBMS, sql is a language which has different providers, mysql, sql server and oracle are all different providers, your question cannot have all of them

Comment: Post what you've tried so far and the result you got.

Comment: @scaisEdge & WhatsThePoint : I am using SQL Server..

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code:

Create table #Temp (Mdate Date,Qty Int)

Declare @S Date='01-Jan-2018',@E Date='26-Jan-2018'
;With Date1
as
(
Select @S Mdate
Union all
Select Dateadd(Day,1,Mdate) Mdate  From Date1
Where Mdate < @E
)
Insert into #Temp
Select Mdate,CAST(((9 + 4) - 4) * RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) + 1 AS int) Qty  From Date1

;With Cte
as
(
Select Mdate,Qty,Sum(Qty) Over(Order by DATEADD(d, 7 - datepart(weekday, dateadd(d, 1, Mdate)), Mdate)) Qty1,
Dense_rank() Over(Order by DATEADD(d, 7 - datepart(weekday, dateadd(d, 1, Mdate)), Mdate)) as Id From #Temp
Group by Mdate,Qty
)
Select Distinct DATEADD(d, 7 - datepart(weekday, dateadd(d, 1, Mdate)), Mdate)Mdate,Qty1 As Qty from Cte